# Use of TJSONAncestor.Owned to keep included Objects after free

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I don't understand the help for the `owned` property of the `TJSONAncestor` Class.

I want to make sure that a `TJSONARRAY`I add to a `TJSONOBJECT`is not freed when I free the `TJSONOBJECT`.

How do I use the `owned` property for this?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, yes sorry, fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Owned` property of `TJSONAncestor` object instance is set to `True`, such object will be automatically managed by its owner object and released when owner object is released.

When `Owned` property is set to `False`, object instance will not be managed and released by its owner and you need to manually release (call `Free`) it yourself.

In other words, if you want to prevent releasing of `TJSONArray` instance you need to set its `Owned` property to `False`.